# Apache Samza's CheckpointTool won't give away partition offsets

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-samza

I am trying to rewind input feed for one of my samza jobs with checkpoint tool as described [here](http://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.9/jobs/reprocessing.html) and [here](http://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.9/container/checkpointing.html). For some reason the checkpoint tool won't output offsets as promised, however I know for a fact that the job has already consumed more than a few messages from the partition in question.

This is a truncated version of the output that the checkpoint tool gives me:

```
2015-06-11 16:31:04 ZkClient [INFO] zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
2015-06-11 16:31:04 ZkEventThread [INFO] Terminate ZkClient event thread.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 ZooKeeper [INFO] Session: 0x14de25b502e01b4 closed
2015-06-11 16:31:04 ClientCnxn [INFO] EventThread shut down
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Checkpoint topic __samza_checkpoint_ver_1_for_test-job1_1 already exists.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Validating checkpoint topic __samza_checkpoint_ver_1_for_test-job1_1.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Successfully validated checkpoint topic __samza_checkpoint_ver_1_for_test-job1_1.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Reading checkpoint for taskName Partition 0
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] No TaskName to checkpoint mapping provided.  Reading for first time.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Connecting to leader pavels-mbp.it.local:9092 for topic __samza_checkpoint_ver_1_for_test-job1_1 and to fetch all checkpoint messages.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Got offset 0 for topic __samza_checkpoint_ver_1_for_test-job1_1 and partition 0. Attempting to fetch messages for checkpoint log.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Get latest offset 31 for topic __samza_checkpoint_ver_1_for_test-job1_1 and partition 0.
2015-06-11 16:31:04 KafkaCheckpointManager [INFO] Got checkpoint state for taskName Partition 0: Checkpoint [offsets={}]
```

This is my `test_job.properties` file:

```
# Job
job.factory.class=org.apache.samza.job.local.ThreadJobFactory
job.name=test-job1

# Task
task.class=com.xim.test.TestTaskClass
task.inputs=kafka.EnergyPurchaseEvent

systems.kafka.samza.factory=org.apache.samza.system.kafka.KafkaSystemFactory
systems.kafka.consumer.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181/
systems.kafka.producer.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

task.checkpoint.factory=org.apache.samza.checkpoint.kafka.KafkaCheckpointManagerFactory
task.checkpoint.system=kafka
task.checkpoint.replication.factor=1
```

As you can see, checkpointing is enabled.